# Unexpected behaviour depicted by find_by id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing a very weird problem, when a string containing number and alphabets is provided to find_by it internally runs to_i on string(as per observation) provided and return the object. I was expecting that it should return nil in that case. Please help me out in this.

```
Shop.find_by(id: '22456a12m3')
```

```
  Shop Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."cancelled_at" IS NULL AND "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 22456], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: By default your `id` column will be an integer. Possibly `BigInt`. Why are you expecting it to be alphanumeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), they call `to_i` for integer id field.

> If the primary key is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments by using `to_i`.